# Drop down is activating when clicked on white space

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How to make sure that the drop-down is activated only when the arrow or the name is clicked. I tried looking at similar questions but it did not work for me. If I click anywhere next to the "shop" the drop-down is being activated.

Here is the code. U can see from the code that the cursor changes to hand anywhere in the horizontal line of the "shop" both left and right.

Edited the code to include inline-block

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- jquery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper for drop down menus -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Load bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="display:inline-block;" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Shop</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu p-0">
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap px-2">
        <div class="mega-dropdown-column py-4 px-3">
          <div class="widget widget-links mb-3">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Shop layouts</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-grid-ls.html">Shop
                                    Grid - Left Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-grid-rs.html">Shop
                                    Grid - Right Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-grid-ft.html">Shop
                                    Grid - Filters on Top</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-list-ls.html">Shop
                                    List - Left Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-list-rs.html">Shop
                                    List - Right Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-list-ft.html">Shop
                                    List - Filters on Top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="widget widget-links">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Marketplace</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-category.html">Category Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-single.html">Single Item Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-vendor.html">Vendor Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-cart.html">Cart</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-checkout.html">Checkout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mega-dropdown-column py-4 px-3">
          <div class="widget widget-links">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Shop pages</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-categories.html">Shop Categories</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-single-v1.html">Product Page v.1</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-single-v2.html">Product Page v.2</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-cart.html">Cart</a>
              </li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-details.html">Checkout - Details</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-shipping.html">Checkout - Shipping</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-payment.html">Checkout - Payment</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-review.html">Checkout - Review</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-complete.html">Checkout - Complete</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="order-tracking.html">Order Tracking</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="comparison.html">Product
                                    Comparison</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mega-dropdown-column py-4 pr-3">
          <div class="widget widget-links mb-3">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Grocery store</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="grocery-catalog.html">Product Catalog</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="grocery-single.html">Single Product Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="grocery-checkout.html">Checkout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <a class="d-block" href="#"><img src="img/shop/menu-banner.jpg" alt="Promo banner"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for both the answers Rishabh and Ken

IF you set padding to zero and display:inline-block it solves my problem

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- jquery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper for drop down menus -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Load bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown text-center"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="padding:0; display:inline-block" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Shop</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu p-0">
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap px-2">
        <div class="mega-dropdown-column py-4 px-3">
          <div class="widget widget-links mb-3">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Shop layouts</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-grid-ls.html">Shop
                                    Grid - Left Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-grid-rs.html">Shop
                                    Grid - Right Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-grid-ft.html">Shop
                                    Grid - Filters on Top</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-list-ls.html">Shop
                                    List - Left Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-list-rs.html">Shop
                                    List - Right Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-list-ft.html">Shop
                                    List - Filters on Top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="widget widget-links">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Marketplace</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-category.html">Category Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-single.html">Single Item Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-vendor.html">Vendor Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-cart.html">Cart</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-checkout.html">Checkout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mega-dropdown-column py-4 px-3">
          <div class="widget widget-links">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Shop pages</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-categories.html">Shop Categories</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-single-v1.html">Product Page v.1</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-single-v2.html">Product Page v.2</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-cart.html">Cart</a>
              </li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-details.html">Checkout - Details</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-shipping.html">Checkout - Shipping</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-payment.html">Checkout - Payment</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-review.html">Checkout - Review</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-complete.html">Checkout - Complete</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="order-tracking.html">Order Tracking</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="comparison.html">Product
                                    Comparison</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mega-dropdown-column py-4 pr-3">
          <div class="widget widget-links mb-3">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Grocery store</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="grocery-catalog.html">Product Catalog</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="grocery-single.html">Single Product Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="grocery-checkout.html">Checkout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <a class="d-block" href="#"><img src="img/shop/menu-banner.jpg" alt="Promo banner"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

Add `display: inline-block` CSS to the a tag.

For example:

```
<a style="display: inline-block;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Shop</a>
```

[image]

#### Reason

The **a** tag responsible for toggling the drop-down was expanding to the full width. So you needed to shrink it.

[image]

Comment: I tired that but it still has some white space (left and right)

Comment: Is that a problem? That's not mentioned in the post.

Comment: Yes, I meant like the drop-down should be activated only when it clicked on the name or the little arrow.  May be it was not clear but I mentioned "How to make sure that the drop-down is activated only when the arrow or the name is clicked."

Comment: Yeah, this solution worked for me to solve that issue. Let me try again myself.

Comment: I added a gif in my answer.

Comment: it is not working for me.. I updated the code snippet to include the "display: inline-block' but it is still showing the same thing. Can you please add the code snippet if it is working for you. That way it is easy to check. You just have to copy the snippet to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First option is: set the `position:absolute;` for the `dropdown` class.

```css
.dropdown,.dropleft,.dropright,.dropup{
    position:absolute!important;
}
.nav-link{
    padding:0!important;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- jquery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper for drop down menus -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Load bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Shop</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu p-0">
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap px-2">
        <div class="mega-dropdown-column py-4 px-3">
          <div class="widget widget-links mb-3">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Shop layouts</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-grid-ls.html">Shop
                                    Grid - Left Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-grid-rs.html">Shop
                                    Grid - Right Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-grid-ft.html">Shop
                                    Grid - Filters on Top</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-list-ls.html">Shop
                                    List - Left Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-list-rs.html">Shop
                                    List - Right Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-list-ft.html">Shop
                                    List - Filters on Top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="widget widget-links">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Marketplace</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-category.html">Category Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-single.html">Single Item Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-vendor.html">Vendor Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-cart.html">Cart</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-checkout.html">Checkout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mega-dropdown-column py-4 px-3">
          <div class="widget widget-links">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Shop pages</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-categories.html">Shop Categories</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-single-v1.html">Product Page v.1</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-single-v2.html">Product Page v.2</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-cart.html">Cart</a>
              </li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-details.html">Checkout - Details</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-shipping.html">Checkout - Shipping</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-payment.html">Checkout - Payment</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-review.html">Checkout - Review</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-complete.html">Checkout - Complete</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="order-tracking.html">Order Tracking</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="comparison.html">Product
                                    Comparison</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mega-dropdown-column py-4 pr-3">
          <div class="widget widget-links mb-3">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Grocery store</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="grocery-catalog.html">Product Catalog</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="grocery-single.html">Single Product Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="grocery-checkout.html">Checkout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <a class="d-block" href="#"><img src="img/shop/menu-banner.jpg" alt="Promo banner"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```

Second option is: set `padding:0;` with `position:absolute` to `.nav-link`

```css
.dropdown,.dropleft,.dropright,.dropup{
    display:flex;
}

.nav-link{
    padding:0!important;
    margin-left:10px;
    position:absolute;
    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- jquery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper for drop down menus -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Load bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Shop</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu p-0">
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap px-2">
        <div class="mega-dropdown-column py-4 px-3">
          <div class="widget widget-links mb-3">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Shop layouts</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-grid-ls.html">Shop
                                    Grid - Left Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-grid-rs.html">Shop
                                    Grid - Right Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-grid-ft.html">Shop
                                    Grid - Filters on Top</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-list-ls.html">Shop
                                    List - Left Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-list-rs.html">Shop
                                    List - Right Sidebar</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-list-ft.html">Shop
                                    List - Filters on Top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="widget widget-links">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Marketplace</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-category.html">Category Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-single.html">Single Item Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-vendor.html">Vendor Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-cart.html">Cart</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="marketplace-checkout.html">Checkout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mega-dropdown-column py-4 px-3">
          <div class="widget widget-links">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Shop pages</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-categories.html">Shop Categories</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-single-v1.html">Product Page v.1</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-single-v2.html">Product Page v.2</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="shop-cart.html">Cart</a>
              </li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-details.html">Checkout - Details</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-shipping.html">Checkout - Shipping</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-payment.html">Checkout - Payment</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-review.html">Checkout - Review</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="checkout-complete.html">Checkout - Complete</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="order-tracking.html">Order Tracking</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="comparison.html">Product
                                    Comparison</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mega-dropdown-column py-4 pr-3">
          <div class="widget widget-links mb-3">
            <h6 class="font-size-base mb-3">Grocery store</h6>
            <ul class="widget-list">
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="grocery-catalog.html">Product Catalog</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="grocery-single.html">Single Product Page</a></li>
              <li class="widget-list-item pb-1"><a class="widget-list-link" href="grocery-checkout.html">Checkout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <a class="d-block" href="#"><img src="img/shop/menu-banner.jpg" alt="Promo banner"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```

If you need anything else, please let me know.

Comment: the width seems to be alright but you can still see the drop-down is being activated in the left side

Comment: I have updated my answer.Please check it now.The cursor was changing in the left side of dropdown, because there was a `padding` generated in the scss.I have set `padding:0;`.

Comment: yes this works. I took part of you answer and ken's answer